# Netsuite Action Script that POSTs to another website?

Tags: rest, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to write a Netsuite SuiteScript that should send messages to another website but I don't seem to be doing it right.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType WorkflowActionScript
 * @NModuleScope public
**/
define(["N/https", "N/log"], function (https, log) {
    function onAction(scriptContext) {
      log.debug(scriptContext);
      return https.post({
        url: "https://myapp.com/netsuite",
        body: JSON.stringify(scriptContext),
      });
    }
  
    return {
      onAction: onAction,
    };
  });
```

This is the script I wrote and I've been uploading it via "Customization > Scripting > Scripts"

I've uploaded it as a workflow action, I think... And had fiddled around with "Parameters" setting an "Input" that would be using the current customer record in the workflow.

I then make a workflow that takes in a saved search and I set the script as an action.

What I'm intending is that anything in that saved search will go through this script and it'll POST a message to my app.

The problem is, once I hit "Execute Now" I never get anything on my applications endpoint. However, if I manually POST a message via postman, it works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you deploy the action to the record type of your workflow?

Comment: @bknights Yessir, let me supply some more details as well. The workflow is one that is deployed to customer records. I don't know if it needs to be deployed to other record types like leads and projects, which are also attached to my customer record I think.

Comment: @Sero Did you try storing the output in the variable and then using log.debug to check? var response = https.put({...}); Give this a try and let me know. ALSO, if possible, try switching to UserEvent and test this once. I have actually faced many issues with Workflow Action Scripts, so if possible, worth a try!

Comment: @Finnick I am trying to just do a log.debug now, but I don't seem to even be getting a debug anywhere... I'm not sure what I'm doing with Netsuite tbh. Been using it less than a month.

Comment: I might have found an alternative method by just using a RESTlet and setting up a polling server to get the results, act on them, and update the record in such a way that it is removed from the saved search.